# Why can’t I delete Items from todo list in JavaScript using this code?

Tags: javascript

I am able to add items to the list. But, I am only able to remove 1 item from the list. After removing 1 item, the code breaks, and I don't know what happened, but this does not work as planned:

- The user should be able to add items to the list.
- The user should be able to delete the desired item from the list.

After the removal of 1 item: I am able to add as many items to the list as I wish, but the delete button stops working.

Code:

```js
'use strict'
const addButton = document.querySelector('#addButton');
const inputArea = document.querySelector('#content');
const listContainer = document.querySelector('#listContainer');

var keyGen = 1;

let arrayOfTodoList = [];

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  renderAgain(inputArea.value);
  inputArea.value = '';
})

function renderAgain(value) {
  let html = `<li>${value}<button class="deleteButton${keyGen++}">Delete</button></li>`;
  arrayOfTodoList.push(html);
  updateNow();
  addEventListenersToDeleteButtons();
}

function updateNow() {
  listContainer.innerHTML = '';
  listContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', arrayOfTodoList.join(''));
  console.log(arrayOfTodoList);
}

function addEventListenersToDeleteButtons() {
  var arrayOfDeleteButtons = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfTodoList.length; i++) {
    arrayOfDeleteButtons.push(document.querySelector(`.deleteButton${i+1}`));
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfDeleteButtons.length; j++) {
    arrayOfDeleteButtons[j].addEventListener("click", () => {
      //alert(event.target.className);
      deleteNow(event.target.className);
    })
  }
  console.log(arrayOfDeleteButtons);
}

function deleteNow(givenClassName) {


  arrayOfTodoList = arrayOfTodoList.filter((element) => {
    if (!element.includes(givenClassName)) {
      return element;
    }
  })


  console.log(arrayOfTodoList);
  updateNow();
  addEventListenersToDeleteButtons();
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <h1>Welcome to <span>TODO</span></h1>
  <input type="text" id="content" />
  <button id="addButton">Add</button>
</div>


<div id="containerTodo">
  <ul id="listContainer">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `addEventListener` function is additive.  So, when you rerun it, it doesn't replace the old event listeners, but adds new ones.

Comment: @phatfingers `innerHTML` most likely removes all event listeners

Comment: @Konrad Ah, I missed that.  I suppose that resetting `keyGen` to 0 each time to match `i` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the conditions, something like this should work:

```
function addEventListenersToDeleteButtons() {
    var arrayOfDeleteButtons = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < keyGen; i++) {
        var tmp=document.querySelector(`.deleteButton${i + 1}`);
        if(tmp!=null){
            arrayOfDeleteButtons.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfDeleteButtons.length; j++) {
        arrayOfDeleteButtons[j].addEventListener("click", () => {
            //alert(event.target.className);
            deleteNow(event.target.className);
        })
    }
    console.log(arrayOfDeleteButtons);
}
```